# given a positive integer $N$, prove there always exist integers $x, y, z,$ such that $\{\sqrt{x}\}+\{\sqrt{y}\} = 1+\{\sqrt{z}\}$ with $x, y, z > N$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

Given a real number $a$, $\{a\}$ denotes the fractional part of $a$, i.e. the only real number with $0\leq \{a\} < 1$ such that $a = \{a\}+k$ for some integer $k$. I have tried this problem but can't seem to get anywhere. How should one approach such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

So in particular, $\sqrt x+\sqrt y-\sqrt z$ is an integer, which is unusual as "essentially different" square roots are linearly independent over the rationals. 
This means that except for trivial cases (i.e., except when at least one of $x,y$ is a perfect square) the desired integer can only be $0$.
This means that we do not need to look for too elaborate and exotic cases.
In fact, the simplest examples to achieve $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=\sqrt z$ are $x=y$ and $z=4x$. The remaining obstacle is that we need $\{\sqrt x\}+\{\sqrt y\}>1$, i.e., $\{\sqrt x\}>\frac12$. Now note that $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt n=\frac1{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt n}<\frac1{2\sqrt n}<\frac12$ for $n\ge1$ so that the desired condition holds in particular when $x$ is one less than a perfect square $>1$.

**Conclusio.** Given $N$ (where wlog $N>1$), let $x=y=N^2-1$ and $z=4N^2-4$.

---

If you are unhappy with $x=y$, experiment with $\sqrt x+2\sqrt x=3\sqrt x$, i.e., $y=4x$, $z=9x$. We just have to be slightly more careful to really have $\{\sqrt x\}+\{\sqrt y\}=1+\{\sqrt z\}$ instead of $\{\sqrt x\}+\{\sqrt y\}=\{\sqrt z\}$: If we (again) take $x=N^2-1$, so $y=4N^2-4$ and $z=9N^2-9$, we have
$$N-\sqrt x=\frac1{N+\sqrt x}\quad\text{and}\quad 2N-\sqrt y=\frac2{N+\sqrt x}$$
and each of these is so kind to be  $<\frac12$ for $N\ge3$.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't figure out a sufficient condition for $\{\sqrt{x}\} > \frac{1}{2}$. Also, how do you prove that $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y} - \sqrt{z} = k$ where $k$ is an integer is only solvable when $k = 0$?
Edit: There actually is a second part to the original question which asks to prove that for all triples $(x, y, z)$ which satisfy the conditions we must have $z > 4N$.

Comment: @LorenzoCatani In this context, that fact is only folklore and not *necessary* to solve the problem (hm, perhaps for the second part you mention in the comment?), but it may at least prevent one from looking too far for examples.  but ...

Comment: ... Loosely speaking, a sum (or rational linear combination) of square roots of integers is zero only if it is so for trivial reasons, i.e., if extracting square factors from under the root (e.g., $\frac32\sqrt{245}\to \frac{21}2\sqrt 5$) allows one to cancel all summands. This theorem is not fully trivial, though. But with it, $\sqrt x+\sqrt y-\sqrt z\pm \sqrt{k^2}=0$ is only possible if one of the given square roots is an integer (i.e., one of $x,y,z$ is a perfect square) and cancels against $\sqrt{k^2}$, or if $k=0$

Comment: For this problem, one can proceed more concretely:  If $\sqrt a\pm \sqrt b=c$, then $a+b\pm\sqrt{4ab}=c^2$ and so $4ab$ is a perfect square. Write $a=rs^2$, $b=rt^2$ with  $r$ squarefree and show that either $r$ must be a perfect square, i.e., $r=1$, or we have $a=b$ and the negative sign in the original equation, which becomes $c=\sqrt a-\sqrt a=0$. -- For $\sqrt x+\sqrt y-\sqrt z=k$, rewrite as $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=k+\sqrt z$, square both sides to obtain $\sqrt{4xy}-2k\sqrt{ z}\in\Bbb Z$ and by the previous case, the assumption $k\ne0$ leads to  ($k>0$ and) $xy=k^2z$. Similarly, $xz=k^2y$. So...

Comment: Sorry but if $a = rs^2$ and $b = rt^2$ then $4ab = (2rst)^2$ so it is a perfect square regardless of the value of $r$. I don't understand how you come to the conclusion that $r=1$ or $a = b$ from this.